# There is no Tags term MENU or MENUS in DA?

Tags: feature-request

Recently, I have asked question of DA regarding the Menu, buy my surprise, there is no Tags term "Menu" or "Menus". All list I show was the name of menu modules. Can somebody please add that term, as I do not have privilege to add.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt `menu` has any standalone value, so I'd suggest making [menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/menu) a synonym for [navigation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation). That tag already has quite some diverse questions regarding menus.

Comment: Ok, If navigation serves the same purpose then there is no need to add menu. I posted this request as It happened to ask question regarding the drupal primary menu, and as a general consciousness I just typed menu as It is most relevant word for that purpose. If user type menu and Navigation appears in autocomplete suggestion then also it would be fine, as that user will come to know that he have to use navigation instead of Menu. Thanks

Comment: Fun fact, I do not have sufficient permissions either (need 5 upvotes on the `navigation` tag), so perhaps one of the mods can do this?

Comment: Hhmm, Yes if moderators can decide on this, it can be done. I do not know if there is some mode to notify them, if then it is good to notify. But I am sure that moderators gets notification regarding the questions which gets posted here as I just found that info, hence they would have come across this question or they will. Might be we will see some comment here from them soon. Moreover this answer and above conversation will help them to decide.

Comment: There is not need to make a synonym, which are used for different purposes. Just use [tag:navigation].

Comment: @kiamlaluno I thought a synonym would show up if I were to type another word. For instance `D7` suggests `7` and `commerce-kickstart` suggests `drupal-commerce`. Wouldn't it make sense to make `menu` suggest `navigation`? I mean, you know it exists, I do, but as the OP states this can be confusing for (relatively) new members.

Comment: Yes, tag synonyms show up when you starting writing part of it, or part of the main tag. The fact is that tag synonyms should be used when there are many users who keep using the wrong tag (which is made synonym of the correct tag). I prefer [tag:menu] not appearing even as synonym simply for the fact [tag:menu] has been used in the past for questions about `hook_menu()`, when the correct tag is [tag:routing].

Comment: The problem is that users select tags without checking they are the right ones; that is why you see users selecting [tag:security] when asking a question about pages viewed with the https:// protocol. Before adding more tag synonyms, I would like to see users editing off the wrong tags from questions.

Comment: (Al right, tag synonyms could also be set to keep the correct tag when a question is migrated from another site, but that is a different case.)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clarifying. Perhaps we should start a new meta discussion to add some tag descriptions? Many tags are ill documented and it is not clear what the intention of the tag is.

Comment: I would be more than happy to see discussions about the tags we use; lately, we accepted too easily tags added from new users who should instead keep using the existing ones. A question for single tag should be fine, if the question doesn't underline a more generic problem.

Comment: And yes, the fact some tags don't have any description is part of the problem; the other one is that users just don't read what the tag is for, and users who can edit questions don't correct the wrong tags.