# Write wiki pages for empty tags to clarify their intention for new and existing users

Tags: discussion, tags

This question arose in [There is no Tags term MENU or MENUS in DA?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/there-is-no-tags-term-menu-or-menus-in-da). The situation is that a lot of tags are vague, wrongly used or created even though there are already alternative tags available.

I suppose this is partially because there are quite a lot of tags which are missing a proper description. Especially pages 6 - 16 of the [tags page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags) have a lot of items with missing descriptions. This makes it difficult for users to choose the tags they want to use, but also for reviewers because we (I) don't know the intended type of questions for some tags either.

Obviously this won't solve the problem for users who 'refuse' to read the questions, but it would solve at least part of the problem where users simply have no idea what tag to choose.

Perhaps some of us should have a look at the exiting tags and document some (bigger) tags? This has been proposed in 2012 as well ([Calling for action: Help improving our tag wikis](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/741/calling-for-action-help-improving-our-tag-wikis)) which holds some guidelines. Can we at least try to get some more excerpts on the tags so people will know what the intention of the tag is?

Personally I'd be happy to write some documentation for some of the bigger tags knowing that it would help current and future users, but I cannot do it all by myself.